# How can I add or subtract days to inputs?

Tags: javascript, calendar, addition

I'm trying to add or subtract some days to inputs that I have. In fact it comes from my registered data from mysql. It give me some days and I would like to add or subtract.

Actually I've done the function for adding days.

Here comes the function::

```
​<script type="text/javascript">
    function addday() {
        var items = new Array();
        var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("date");

        for (var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++) {
            items[i] = document.getElementById("date" + (i + 1)).value;
        }



        for (var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++) {
            items[i] = document.getElementById("date" + (i + 1)).value;
            var itemDtParts = items[i].split("-");
            var itemDt = new Date(itemDtParts[2], itemDtParts[1] - 1, itemDtParts[0]);
            nb=document.getElementById('nb')

                itemCount[i].value = (itemDt.getDate() < 9 ? "0" : "")+ (itemDt.getDate()+nb)+ "-" + (itemDt.getMonth() < 9 ? "0" : "") + (itemDt.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + itemDt.getFullYear();





        }
       return items;
       }
</script>
```

the real concern is that instead of giving me the day plus the number of day that I wrote in the input field for that.

It displays to me something like that:

27[object HTMLInputElement]-08-2012

So I do not know how to change it.

Receive all my utmost respect.

thank you very much for your help.

SP.

Comment: Please share html also for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
nb=document.getElementById('nb')
```

To:

```
nb=document.getElementById('nb').value;
```

and you should be good

Comment: I'm very sorry for the mistakes. But I learn english since six month and it is not very easy because I learn also russian and german. I will Try this.

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski - I'm sure your English is far better than my German and Russian!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've done that changment the concern is actualy that Instead of writting a correct date it write the date  + the numvber of days for example If I we were the 10 of August and I put + 5 days Instead of giving 15 August it give 105 of august which does not exist

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski Sorry, javascript doesn't have a built in add function for dates. Try the function in http://www.solutionbot.com/2008/06/20/javascript-dateadd-function/

Comment: Ok thanks I will try to find an other way.

Receive Sir my utmost Respect.

Sp

Answer (score 0):

```
nb=document.getElementById('nb')

itemCount[i].value = (itemDt.getDate() < 9 ? "0" : "")+ (itemDt.getDate()+nb)+ "-" + (itemDt.getMonth() < 9 ? "0" : "") + (itemDt.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + itemDt.getFullYear();
```

itemCount[i].value seems to be strange. I suppose it should be items[i]

Also I think the first if statement duplicates the second one.

Comment: no in fact it is the good thing. The concern is just that there is no addition of days just they are put after. for example 10 august + 5 days give me 105 august instead of 15